# How to change SPListItem.Level property?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splistitem

I would like to change SPlistitem.Level property in programally.
but now , I create program. SPlistitem.Level property is Read Only property. and I try to SPFile.Level property too. but now result is same.

so anyone please how to change SPlistItem.Level Property in programally.

Thanks regard.

Answer (score 1):

The [Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.level?view=sharepoint-server) property is a read-only property that indicates whether a file is checked out, checked in as a draft minor version, or published as a major version.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilelevel?view=sharepoint-server), the three possible values are:

- Checkout
- Draft
- Published

To change the value, perform the appropriate operation on the item's `File` property.

To check it out: `SPListItem.File.CheckOut()`
To check it in: `SPListItem.File.CheckIn()`
To publish it: `SPlistItem.File.Publish()`